# Scala Populate List of Maps by Splitting

Tags: scala

I have a dataset coming from database looks like:

```
rows: List[Map[String, String]

0: ("attribute1","value1"), ("attribute2", "value2"), ("attribute3", "value3,value4,value5")
...
```

Calculation for attribute3 is done by GROUP_CONCAT function in a MySQL script in a nightly task, so I can't populate the data in the database side.

What I need is to populate this data set for attribute3 by splitting via delimiter ",".

Expected output for the example above is:

```
rowsPopulated: List[Map[String, String]

0: ("attribute1","value1"), ("attribute2", "value2"), ("attribute3", "value3")
1: ("attribute1","value1"), ("attribute2", "value2"), ("attribute3", "value4")
2: ("attribute1","value1"), ("attribute2", "value2"), ("attribute3", "value5")
...
```

I can get all values splittend into lists by following code but it's not even close to my end goal...

```
rows.map(x => x.get("attribute3").getOrElse("").split(','))
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
val rows = List(Map(
  "attribute1" -> "value1", 
  "attribute2" -> "value2", 
  "attribute3" -> "foo,bar,baz"
))

rows.flatMap( row =>
  row.getOrElse("attribute3", "").split(",")
     .map(a3 => row.updated("attribute3", a3))
)
```

Comment: or the last part with a for comprehension
  for {
     row <- rows
     a3 <- row.getOrElse("attribute3", "").split(",")
  yield row.updated("attribute3", a3)